# Which indexes to create on a table that will contain millions of rows and multiple filters

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with millions of rows. Users can select any combination of filters on multiple columns. For ex:

1. Year
2. Month
3. Product
4. HSCode
5. Chapter
6. Country
7. Port
8. Unit
9. Importer/exporter name
   10.Type

I am planning to make it mandatory to select the Year filter. So that index on Year filter is always used to improve the query performance.

Since any combination of these filters be used (single, multiple, all)- What kind of indexes I should have on the table? The table is going to be really huge and it is important to maintain the read performance on these queries

Answer (score 1):

1. Discover what queries are typically used.
2. Make a dozen or so 2-column indexes based on typical queries.

When making composite indexes:

- Have the column(s) tested with `=` first.
- When a column is tested with a range (`IN`, `LIKE`, `BETWEEN`, etc), subsequent columns in the index may go unused.
- `LIKE 'no-wild-cards'` and `IN ('one option') are the same as` =`.
- `LIKE 'blah%' is a "range" test.
- `LIKE '%blah` cannot use an index.
- Have an extra column for all "text" searches; toss all the "text" columns into it.  (Optionally remove punctuation.)  Then use `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH`.
- `Year` and `Month` can be problematic; let's see some concrete examples.

See also [*EAV*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a search engine like [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for the task you describe.

The problem with using conventional MySQL indexing is that they have a fixed number of columns, the columns are in order, and searches must make use of the columns from the first one.

Compare with looking up a name in a telephone book. You can look up a person by their last name, because the last name is the first column in the index. But if you need to search for someone by first name only, it's not the first column in the index, and the sort order of the book does not help.

So to optimize searching by any columns in your search criteria, you'd need N-factorial indexes for N columns.

Whereas using a search engine like Apache Solr doesn't use the same kind of indexing. You can search the Solr index with any subset of attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The entire application is based on this one table so it's difficult to change it to solr now. I would like to understand the best way to handle this in MySQL itself

Comment: You could try MySQL's fulltext index. But if you use regular indexes, you must know the columns to be selected.